# trying to group by date for datetime type but not time with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table as follows:

```
  block int not null
  day datetime not null
  user int
```

i want to

```
  select day, count(*) 
  from TABLE 
  where date between date() and TARDATE 
  group by day 
  order by day desc
```

The thing is, that i want to group by date only, and not time.

How would i do that in MySQL/php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT DATE(`day`) as `DAY`, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  date BETWEEN date() AND TARDATE 
GROUP BY DATE(`day`)
ORDER BY day DESC
```

Comment: Will this be also doing it with month and year?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT DATE(day), COUNT(*) as total_no FROM TABLE WHERE  date ( BETWEEN date() AND TARDATE ) GROUP BY DATE(day) ORDER BY day DESC
```